# Remove " Browse Category : " from Archive title

Tags: templates

I have the Shaped Blog theme and I try to remove "Browse Category:" from my Archive title.

I look in the code and found in "template-tags.php" this code :

`    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Archive title
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'shaped_blog_archive_title' ) ) :

function shaped_blog_archive_title( $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Category: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Tag: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Author: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Year: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'shaped-blog' ) ) );
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Month: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'shaped-blog' ) ) );
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Day: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F j, Y', 'daily archives date format', 'shaped-blog' ) ) );
    } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format' ) ) {
        if ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-aside' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Asides', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-gallery' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Galleries', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-image' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Images', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-video' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Videos', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-quote' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Quotes', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-link' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Links', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-status' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Statuses', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-audio' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Audio', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-chat' ) ) {
            $title = _x( 'Chats', 'post format archive title', 'shaped-blog' );
        }
    } elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Browse Archives: %s', 'shaped-blog' ), post_type_archive_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_tax() ) {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        /* translators: 1: Taxonomy singular name, 2: Current taxonomy term */
        $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s: %2$s', 'shaped-blog' ), $tax->labels->singular_name, single_term_title( '', false ) );
    } else {
        $title = __( 'Archives', 'shaped-blog' );
    }

    /**
     * Filter the archive title.
     *
     * @param string $title Archive title to be displayed.
     */
    $title = apply_filters( 'get_the_archive_title', $title );

    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        echo $before . $title . $after;
    }
}
endif;
```

`

I don't understand how to remove it despite the little explanation at the end.

Thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`child theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Add filter in the `functions.php` of child theme like this.

```
add_filter('get_the_archive_title','wpse_224884_filter_archive_title',10,1);
function wpse_224884_filter_archive_title($title){
   if ( is_category() ) {
      $title = sprintf( __( '%s', 'shaped-blog' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
   } 
   return $title;
}
```

Or

Copy the entire function into functions.php

```
function shaped_blog_archive_title( $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
    $title = sprintf( __( '%s', 'shaped-blog' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
  }else if ....//remaining code
}
```

without `if ( ! function_exists( 'shaped_blog_archive_title' ) ) :`

The only change you need to do is remove **Browse Category:** in line 4